# Using Reachability on iOS to choose an appropriate index file in m3u8 (HLS)

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, m3u8, avplayeritem

According to [Apple's HTTP Live Streaming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html):

> If you are an iOS app developer, you can query the user’s device to
>   determine whether the initial connection is cellular or WiFi and
>   choose an appropriate master index file.

I understand how to use Reachability to determine the connection, however, I don't understand how to tell AVPlayer to load a different file in the index file of the m3u8.

I'm a bit confused, maybe it does this automatically? But then I don't understand why they suggest that you do this. (Ultimately, I'd like to make sure that even on a 3G/Edge connection my video plays as quickly as possible, so I want to make sure I'm loading the appropriate file for playing).

Answer (score 0):

They suggest creating multiple **master** `m3u8` playlists not choosing a variant from the master (which has the downside of preventing switching to another stream if the network conditions change).

> To ensure the user has a good experience when the stream is first played, regardless of the initial network connection, *you should have more than one master index file consisting of the same alternate index files but with a different first stream*.

The first variant in the master playlist is always loaded first and it's used to determine which bitrate the player can support.

So you can either have two master files with different variants for celluar/WiFi *or* two master files with the same streams but re-ordered so that the first stream is consistent with the network type.

In your code you would determine the network type and request one master URL or the other.